# ngOnit is not executed when when the app-routing module loads the component

Tags: angular

This ngOnInit does not execute the console.log line

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.loadBlogPosts();
  this.authStatusService.getAuthUsername().subscribe(
    status => {
      // got username status
      console.log("This is the username status from home", status);
      this.authUsername = status;
    }
  );
}
```

This line is executed

```
this.loadBlogPosts();
```

This line is not executed:

```
console.log("This is the username status from home", status);
```

This is the app-module.ts.

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },

  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'add', component: BlogPostAddEditComponent  },
  { path: 'posts', component: BlogPostsComponent },
  { path: 'post', component: BlogPostComponent },
  { path: 'auth', component: AuthComponent },
  { path: 'blogpost/:id', component: BlogPostComponent },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '/' }
];
```

This is the app.component.html

```
<app-headernav></app-headernav>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

This is the service:

```
export class AuthStatusService {

  authUsernameChange: Subject<string> = new Subject<string>();

  constructor() { }


  public getAuthUsername(): Observable<string> {
     return this.authUsernameChange.asObservable();
   }

   public setAuthUsername(user: string) {
       this.authUsernameChange.next(user);
     }
}
```

Comment: Could you please show the definition of `getAuthUsername()` function?

Comment: @MichaelD it is added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with `ngOnInit` here. `this.authStatusService.getAuthUsername()` returns an observable, so the handler in this code:

```
this.authStatusService.getAuthUsername().subscribe(
    status => {
      // got username status
      console.log("This is the username status from home", status);
      this.authUsername = status;
    }
  );
```

will only execute when the observable emits a new value. `ngOnInit` is only registering the observable handler method. You need to emit a value somewhere after the call to `ngOnInit` maybe with `this.authStatusService.setAuthUsername(something)`; If you need the last emitted value you should use a `BehaviorSubject` instead of `Subject` in `authUsernameChange`

```
 authUsernameChange: BehaviorSubject <string> = new BehaviorSubject <string>(initialValue);
```

Comment: Thanks Alex. I never would have thought of this! I had to learn the difference between subject and behaviorsubject the hard way.

Comment: @donotbea glad to help